# Cygwin: Unable to find Java path.

Tags: unix, path, cygwin

I am using cygwin on windows 7 env and it is unable to locate java, error message i get is that

```
ERROR: /cygdrive/c/Program
Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_22 does not exist!
```

wired path is if I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` then it shows me

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_22
```

not sure what is happening here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the pathname contains spaces. You need to escape the spaces as described here:

http://www.cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.filename-spaces

Adding this line to your .bashrc should do it:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_22'
```

**Edit:** You could try running this script which I found in this [blog post](http://mike.hostetlerhome.com/2009/09/01/getting-cygwin-and-java-to-play-together/):

```
case "`uname`" in
  CYGWIN*) cygwin=true ;;

esac

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin; then
  JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
  CLASSPATH=`cygpath --windows --path "$CLASSPATH"`
fi
```

Comment: i have placed backlash and still it is not recognizing it.

Comment: i already have that command mentioned in my `.bashrc` file, not sure why it is not picking it up.

Comment: Are you able to move the JDK to a different directory, so that the pathname doesn't contain spaces?

Comment: Let me try that out, hope there are no other related dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Use the old school way:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.6.0_22
```

It worked for me.